# How to load an excel file into qlik sense

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

How can I load an excel file into qlik sense?

The data is already in the file, I want to add it into my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Load an excel file into Qlik Sense..

**If creating a new app:**

- Select Create new app > name your app > Open
- Choose Quick data load
- Browse to the path of your Excel file > Select it > Click Select
- This will then bring up the Select Data screen and by default it will pick up your headers
- Then click Load data

**If adding to an existing app:**

- Open your app
- Click the menu drop down in the top right (icon is 3 bullet pointed lines) > Select Quick data load
- Select whether you want to add data to what you have in the app or replace the data
- Browse to the path of your Excel file > Select it > Click Select
- This will then bring up the Select Data screen and by default it will pick up your headers
- Then click Load data